# Can I have multi-master aws aurora in serverless v2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I do not see option to have a cluster with two writers in serverless v2 for both
Amazon Aurora MySQL-Compatible Edition
Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL-Compatible Edition

Now UI propose us to create a read replica for faster failover.

[image]

But is it possible to have a ready stand by writer? So in case if there is an upgrade or something and I can not get connection opened for a writer, I can just immediately switch to another writer.
Is it possible to have it like this or maybe I missed/misunderstood  something?

Documentation for creation of multi master db is outdated
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-multi-master.html#aurora-multi-master-creating

Answer (score 0):

Correct, multi-master for Aurora is tied to the MySQL 5.6-compatible edition. It isn't available for MySQL 5.7-compatible, MySQL 8.0-compatible, or PostgreSQL-compatible editions. Serverless v2 requires relatively recent versions of the MySQL and PostgreSQL engines, so multi-master definitely isn't available there.

Let's consider the possibilities for the single-writer case, because that's what's available in the versions that are compatible with Serverless v2 and aren't approaching EOL.

If there's an unplanned outage for the writer, Aurora automatically promotes a reader to take its place (failover).

More on failover generally here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.AuroraHighAvailability.html#Concepts.AuroraHighAvailability.Instances
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Concepts.AuroraHighAvailability.html#Aurora.Managing.FaultTolerance

Aurora PostgreSQL has some features and settings to minimize failover time:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.BestPractices.FastFailover.html

If you want to e.g. switch the writer to a higher-capacity instance class, traditionally the way to do that was to make that change on a reader and then promote that to be the new writer by doing a manual failover. Serverless v2 does such capacity changes automatically without a reboot, and it preserves open connections too. So this former reason for reboots/outages isn't applicable in Serverless v2.

In Aurora MySQL 2.10 and higher, you can reboot the writer and the reader instances are still available for queries while the writer is rebooting: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_RebootCluster.html

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation:

> Currently, multi-master clusters require Aurora MySQL version 1, which is compatible with MySQL 5.6. When specifying the DB engine version in the AWS Management Console, AWS CLI, or RDS API, choose 5.6.10a

Here is the link for reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-multi-master.html

Comment: Two thigs I still did not get
1st - Aurora MySQL-Compatible Edition version 1 (with MySQL 5.6 compatibility) will reach end of life on February 28, 2023
To avoid a required upgrade soon, choose Aurora MySQL version 2 or higher.

2nd - even with global_10a and this warning about end of life, UI still shows next
Create an Aurora Replica or Reader node in a different AZ (recommended for scaled availability)
Creates an Aurora Replica for fast failover and high availability.

There is no multi-master

Comment: Info in documentation link is outdated, you can not create it like that anymore